# Jetty IncludeCipherSuites

Tags: security, encryption, web, jetty, jetty-9

i face the issue, that my jetty (9.4.7) doesn't want to start due a configuration error after including CipherSuites in jetty-ssl.xml.

I just receive following configuration error:

```
2018-09-13 16:10:02.896:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <Set name="IncludeCipherSuites">|/jetty-ssl.xml
2018-09-13 16:10:02.897:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory"><Set name="IncludeCipherSuites">|            <Array l
2018-09-13 16:10:02.897:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main:
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration$1: class org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.setIncludeCipherSuites(class [Ljava.lang.String;)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1507)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:506)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:78)
Caused by:
org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration$1: class org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.setIncludeCipherSuites(class [Ljava.lang.String;)
```

I've used the following xml to include Cipher Suites:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "configure_9_3.dtd">

<!-- ============================================================= -->
<!-- Base SSL configuration                                        -->
<!-- This configuration needs to be used together with 1 or more   -->
<!-- of jetty-https.xml or jetty-http2.xml                         -->
<!-- ============================================================= -->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Add a SSL Connector with no protocol factories              -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call  name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New id="sslConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptors" deprecated="ssl.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.selectors" deprecated="ssl.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <!-- uncomment to support proxy protocol
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ProxyConnectionFactory"/>
            </Item>-->
          </Array>
        </Arg>

        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.ssl.host" deprecated="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.ssl.port" deprecated="ssl.port" default="20743" /></Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.ssl.idleTimeout" deprecated="ssl.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
        <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="jetty.ssl.soLingerTime" deprecated="ssl.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" deprecated="ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptQueueSize" deprecated="ssl.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
        <Get name="SelectorManager">
          <Set name="connectTimeout"><Property name="jetty.ssl.connectTimeout" default="15000"/></Set>
          <Set name="reservedThreads"><Property name="jetty.ssl.reservedThreads" default="-2"/></Set>
        </Get>

        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
            <Set name="IncludeCipherSuites">
            <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305</Item>
            <Item>ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305</Item>
            <Item>ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256</Item>
            <Item>ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256</Item>
            <Item>ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384</Item>
            <Item>ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384</Item>
            <Item>DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256</Item>
            <Item>DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384</Item>
            <Item>ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256</Item>
            <Item>ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256</Item>
     <Item>ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA</Item>
            <Item>ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384</Item>
            <Item>ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA</Item>
     <Item>ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384</Item>
            <Item>ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA</Item>
     <Item>ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA</Item>
            <Item>DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256</Item>
            <Item>DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA</Item>
            <Item>DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256</Item>
            <Item>DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA</Item>
            <Item>ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA</Item>
            <Item>ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA</Item>
            <Item>EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA</Item>
            <Item>AES128-GCM-SHA256</Item>
            <Item>AES256-GCM-SHA384</Item>
            <Item>AES128-SHA256</Item>
            <Item>AES256-SHA256</Item>
            <Item>AES128-SHA</Item>
            <Item>AES256-SHA</Item>
            <Item>DES-CBC3-SHA</Item>
            </Array>
            </Set>
        </New>


      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Create a TLS specific HttpConfiguration based on the        -->
  <!-- common HttpConfiguration defined in jetty.xml               -->
  <!-- Add a SecureRequestCustomizer to extract certificate and    -->
  <!-- session information                                         -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <New id="sslHttpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
    <Arg><Ref refid="httpConfig"/></Arg>
    <Call name="addCustomizer">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer">
          <Arg name="sniHostCheck" type="boolean"><Property name="jetty.ssl.sniHostCheck" default="true"/></Arg>
          <Arg name="stsMaxAgeSeconds" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.stsMaxAgeSeconds" default="-1"/></Arg>
          <Arg name="stsIncludeSubdomains" type="boolean"><Property name="jetty.ssl.stsIncludeSubdomains" default="false"/></Arg>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </New>

</Configure>
```

I've also tried different ways of setting this CipherSuites, but always it ends in the same behavior. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What if you change from org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory to org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslSocketConnector

Comment: I'll go anyway with adding the IncludeCipherSuites set outside of the class

Comment: That list of cipher suites has many issues. if you are using jetty-home/jetty-distribution then you shouldn't be editing jetty-ssl.xml. Also none of those cipher names exist on Java (by those names).  Where did you get that list?  Are you using the RFC cipher suite names?  What are you attempting to accomplish? (the end goal, not the steps to it)

Comment: Hi, the issue i currently got is, that if i try to browse to the jetty site, i just receive following error message "SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP".

Comment: Note: Jetty 9.4.7 is subject of several [CVEs](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00123.html), it would be wise to upgrade to Jetty 9.4.12 soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong class was used.

Had to use `<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">`

Problem is solved. 
Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">` I assume.